# What's the Difference between shunt battery charger and battery protection IC?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I don't understand well the difference between shunt battery charger and battery protection IC. Here, component datasheets that I would want to use :

- shunt battery charger : http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/4070fc.pdf
- Battery protectio IC : https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/2/5/1/DW01-P_DataSheet_V10.pdf

May I use them at the same time? 
Do you think they're compatible?

Comment: Just a comment for the future: you wrote a reasonable question (should be expanded a bit by comparing the relevant parts of the two datasheets, but it's not all that horrible as is), and spent relevant time writing it. It would, however, look far more professional, if you abandoned the habit of using "u" instead of "you". You're saving half a second by using "u", but you're wasting easily 25% of my sympathy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you would need both in a battery pack and external charger.

The protection IC is one per cell with 2 external Complementary FETs to provide perfect active balancing and protection from overcharge /current etc for parallel cells *but not series cell balancing.* It adds cost but adds law suit avoidance protection from exploding batteries.

This makes them more reliable in case of 1 flawed battery exploding the whole pack.